# Noob Concern: Assigning a value to variable from new class object. C#

Tags: c#

```
DinnerFun dinnerFun = new DinnerFun { PeepQty = (int)nudPeepQty.Value };
```

I am creating a new object of the DinnerFun class and trying to assign the value from the numeric up down object from the form to the int variable PeepQty.

When I go into debug mode, I can see that sure enough nudPeepQty has a numeric value, but it is never assigned to PeepQty, and my ending calculation always ends as 0.

As the problem might be something related to something I've done outside this line of code, I will add the rest of my project below:

### DinnerParty.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MonuEventPlanning
{
    class DinnerFun
    {
        const int FoodCost = 25;
        public int PeepQty;
        decimal CostOfBeverage;
        decimal CostOfDecorations;
        decimal TotalCost; 

        public void CalcDrinks(bool HealthOption)
        {
            if (HealthOption)
            {
                CostOfBeverage = 5M;
            }
            else
            {
                CostOfBeverage = 20M;
            }
        }

        public void CalcDecorations(bool FancyOption)
        {
            if (FancyOption)
            {
                CostOfDecorations = (PeepQty * 15M) + 50M; 
            }
            else
            {
                CostOfDecorations = (PeepQty * 7.5M) + 30M; 
            }
        }

        public decimal CalcTotalCost(bool HealthyOption)
        {
            if (HealthyOption)
            {
                TotalCost = (CostOfDecorations + CostOfBeverage) * .95M;
                return TotalCost; 
            }
            else
            {
                TotalCost = (CostOfBeverage + CostOfDecorations) + (PeepQty*25M);
                return TotalCost; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

------------Form1.cs -------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MonuEventPlanning
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DinnerFun dinnerFun = new DinnerFun { PeepQty = (int)nudPeepQty.Value };
            dinnerFun.CalcDrinks(cbxHealthy.Checked);
            dinnerFun.CalcDrinks(cbxFancy.Checked);
            DisplayCost(); 
        }

        public void DisplayCost()
        {
            DinnerFun dinnerFun = new DinnerFun(); 
            tbxDisplayCost.Text = dinnerFun.CalcTotalCost(cbxHealthy.Checked).ToString("c"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said in an earlier comment, you can just edit your own question.

Comment: Are these two code blocks supposed to be different somehow? If so I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I think you pasted the same file in there twice. Really need to see the DinnerFun class implementation to help you.

Comment: :P  noted, I will do so.  = P

Comment: What happens when you instantiate a new DinnerFun and explicitly sign it an integer?

Comment: Rename the second variable "anotherDinnerNotTheSameAsTheFirst".  Fix it by giving the DisplayCost method an argument.

Comment: Notice how you call `CalcDrinks` twice. Shouldn't the second one of those be `CalcDecorations`?

Comment: Yeah, that was an unrelated mistake.  I changed it to call CalcDecorations now.  Thank you for pointing that out.  But I'm still getting a zero for my calculation.  I changed { PeepQty = (int)nudPeepQty.Value }; to { PeepQty = 5 };

And my end result was still zero...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating another DinnerFun that is not the same as the first one. Naturally the DinnerFun object in DisplayCost will have zero for the property value. Perhaps you meant this...

```
    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DinnerFun dinnerFun = new DinnerFun { PeepQty = (int)nudPeepQty.Value };
        dinnerFun.CalcDrinks(cbxHealthy.Checked);
        dinnerFun.CalcDrinks(cbxFancy.Checked);
        DisplayCost(dinnerFun); 
    }

    public void DisplayCost(DinnerFun dinnerFun)
    {
        tbxDisplayCost.Text = dinnerFun.CalcTotalCost(cbxHealthy.Checked).ToString("c"); 
    }
```

Comment: You're right.  That was a part of the problem.  But when I remove that new DinnerFun object... it says that dinnerFun does not exist in the current context.  Even if I change the button click method to a public void...

Comment: nevermind... i figured out where I should be declaring dinnerFun.  Thanks for your help.  I REALLY appreciate... it gives this green young grasshopper of a programmer hope to know folks like you are out doing good.  =D

Comment: No worries... anything to help. SO is a good place to get good answers and there are even better programmers than me here also.